# rails refactor model gives an error of Cannot rename instance variable '@search' to local 'rl_search'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I need to refactor my tables so that the table names have a prefix. I.e. searches becomes rl_searches.

When I ran a refactor of searches.rb to rl_searches.rb, I got an error of

> Cannot rename instance variable '@search' to local 'rl_search'

If I show the conflicts in a view, one example is:

```
 def destroy
@search.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to searches_url, notice: 'Search was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_search
  @search = Search.find(params[:id])
end
```

My initial thought is that I can probably refactor the model not force the refactor of the variables. Will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can explicitly set the [table name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name)

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name
    "rl_" + super
  end
end
```

Comment: I also found that you can add  config.active_record.table_name_prefix = 'pre_'  to config/application.rb:

I do have a problem in that some gems have their own data files that don't seem to be affected by changes to the models or application.rb. I'm looking at the possibilty of using schemas to segregate things.